# Multiple preg_replace on a variable

Tags: php, preg-replace

It is safe to use multiple preg_replace and str_replace on a variable?

```
$this->document->setDescription(tokenTruncate(str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), ' ', preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ',preg_replace("/[^\w\d ]/ui", ' ', $custom_meta_description))),160));
```

This is a code which I am using to remove newlines, whitespaces and all non-alphanumeric characters (excluding unicode). The last preg_replace is for the non-alphanumeric characters, but dots are removed too. Is there any way to keep dots, commas, - separators?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example of such a string and its expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be done in a single expression:

```
preg_replace('/(?:\s|[^\w.,-])+/u', ' ', $custom_meta_description);
```

It replaces either spaces (tabs, newlines as well) or things that aren't word-like, digits or punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do can be achieved with a single `preg_replace` statement:

```
$str = preg_replace('#\P{Xwd}++#', '', $str);
$this->document->setDescription($desc, tokenTruncate($str, 160));
```

The above `preg_replace()` statement will replace anything that's not a Unicode digit, letter or whitespace from the supplied string.

See the [Unicode Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) for more details.

Comment: Hmmm, te output is like this "Topeak Sada dielensk� ho n�" - � should be á

Comment: `\p{Xan}` doesn't include underscore `_`. It's better to use `\p{Xwd}`.